# Почему выводит такой результат?

Tags: javascript

```js
const message = "Welcome to Ukraine!"
let messages = [message.split("")];
console.log(messages);
console.log(messages.indexOf("l"));
messages = messages.join("");
console.log(messages);
```

Выводит: `"W,e,l,c,o,m,e, ,t,o, ,U,k,r,a,i,n,e,!"`

Я хочу: `"Welcome to Ukraine!"`

Comment: `[message.split("")];` - а зачем тут квадратные скобки?

Comment: Вам чтобы найти индекс буквы не обязательно сплитить строку. Просто message.indexOf("l"). Ну и да - квадратные скобки здесь let messages = [message.split("")]; не нужны, судя по всему